# How to add overlay on the avplayer video in obj c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, overlay, avplayer

```
- (void)playMethod
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media///bbb-360p.mp4"];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    //to rotate to the landscape on click of play button
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];

    //to open the view
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,667,375);
    controller.player = player;
    controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;




    CALayer* overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    UIImage* overlayImage = nil;

    overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];
    //Create the parent layer
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

    [parentLayer addSublayer: videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer: overlayLayer];

    //Composes the composited video frame with a core animation layer
    AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool *animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer inLayer: parentLayer];




    // to add the back button on player
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(backMethod)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     button1.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, CGRectGetMinY(controller.view.frame)+10, 160.0, 40.0);
    button1.tag = 1001;
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    [controller.view  bringSubviewToFront:button1];
    [player pause];
    [player play];
}
```

I am trying to add the overlay on the video ,but by using the above code nothing happened . Can you please suggest how should I proceed with the code . I am not able to see any effect on the video ,its all same as that of before .

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the **contentOverlayView** property of your AVPlayerViewController. Please find sample code in my answer here: [AVPlayer UITapGestureRecognizer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878609/avplayer-uitapgesturerecognizer-not-working/48797984#48797984)